# Which article must I use and why?

Tags: grammar, articles

Would you please explain the difference between the following?

> **The** average American city requires a prodigious amount of fish daily.

And:

> **An** average American city requires a prodigious amount of fish daily.

Comment: These are Generic Noun Phrases. Neither of them is talking about one city, but rather about the set of American cities which are called "average", for some definition of "average". The first sentence is an example of a Definite Generic NP, the second of an Indefinite Generic NP. You might as well add _Average American cities require a prodigious amount of fish daily_, which is an example of the Plural Generic NP. [Explanations here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).